# How to prove that $X^{T}X$ is singular if $X$ is singular.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

Let's suppose $X$ is $n \times m$ not full rank matrix (ie any column vector in $X$ can be expressed as linear combination of others column vectors). If $$B = X^TX$$
why $B$ is singular?

The question is inspired from the statistics, wherein, if vector of independent variable is linearly dependent, then it is assumed that $X^TX$ is also dependent (or singular). It is difficult to grasp if $X$ is dependent then how $X^TX$ is dependent?

Comment: How do you define “singular matrix” for non-square matrices?

Comment: You should state that X is not full column rank

Comment: @gimusi thanks for suggestion

Comment: @Neeraj “not full column rank” suffices, the point is that $Null(X)\neq \emptyset$ thus exists v such that $Xv=0$ then $X^TXv=X^T0=0$ and thus $X^TX$ is singular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exists $v\neq0$ such that

$$Xv=0$$

then

$$X^TXv=0$$

Comment: can you please elaborate your first statement? what does it mean and from where it comes from?

Comment: @Neeraj  The point is that $Null(X)\neq \emptyset$ thus exists v such that $Xv=0$ then $X^TXv=X^T0=0$ and thus $X^TX$ is singular. Recall that A is not singular if $Av=0 \iff v=0$

Comment: @gimsuin Thanks a lot

Comment: You are welcome! Bye